# how to check whether a dates is between two dates in apex trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

15/4/2017 to 17/4/2017 these dates I've saved already in payroll records with name XXX. 
Now If I save the dates between already given dates with same name XXX it'll produce error. 
for example pairs

14/4/2017 to 16/4/2017

or 13/4/2017 to 16/4/2017

or 13/4/2017 to 18/4/2017 .

Comment: which date? created date or modified date ?

Comment: custom date fields. date1 and date2. old date values should be used again while enter the trigger.new values in date field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you need to compare whether entered dates are between both of those dates which are already there in your system. Try below code:

```
    oldList = [SELECT Name, StartDate, EndDate FROM Object WHERE Name = 'XXX' ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 9999];

for(Object newRecord: (List<Object>)Trigger.new){
    for(Object oldData : oldList ) {

        if(((newRecord.StartDate >= oldData.StartDate && newRecord.StartDate < oldData.EndDate) || 
        (newRecord.EndDate > oldData.StartDate && newRecord.EndDate <= oldData.EndDate)))  {

            //your code goes here
        }
    }
}
```

let me explain above `if` statements:

1. `(newRecord.StartDate >= oldData.StartDate && newRecord.StartDate < oldData.EndDateTime)`: This statement compares that, is `newRecord`'s startDate is greater than or equal to `oldData`'s startDate and `newRecord` startDate is less than `oldData` endDate.

2.`(newRecord.EndDate > oldData.StartDate && newRecord.EndDate <= oldData.EndDateTime)`: This statement compares that, is `newRecord`'s endDate is greater than or equal to `oldData`'s startDate and `newRecord` endDate is less than `oldData` endDate.

3. `(newRecord.Name == oldData.Name)`: This checks if their Name's are same.

Comment: Thanks for ur response. trigger DateValidation on date__c (before insert) {
    
    
    if(((newRecord.StartDate >= oldData.StartDate && newRecord.StartDate < oldData.EndDate) || 
(newRecord.EndDate > oldData.StartDate && newRecord.EndDate <= oldData.EndDate)) 
&& (newRecord.Name == oldData.Name))  {
}    .. here i can I get and use the olddata start and end dates. bcoz it may be more than one records. also trigger.new may be more one records.. i need to use the map/ set/list in this task

Comment: @fazahkhan Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

To find the overlapping date range use like this:

```
Date dtStart = Date.newInstance(2017,04,15); 
Date dtEnd = Date.newInstance(2017,4,17); 
Date dtFirstDt= Date.newInstance(2017,4,14);
Date dtLastDt= Date.newInstance(2017,4,16);

if((dtFirstDt > dtStart && dtFirstDt  < dtEnd ) || (dtLastDt > dtStart && dtLastDt  < dtEnd ))
{
    //date is overlapping

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have date fields, so the only thing you need is to compare existing and new values. You can simply achieve it by comparing existing start and new end and existing end with a new start. For example:

```
if (newStartDate < existingEndDate && newEndDate > existingStartDate) {
    // overlap detected!
}
```

You only need these 2 checks to detect the overlapping dates.